# Strip leading zero from number stored as varchar

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-update

I am trying to query from a table in SQL server. I do not have the rights to update tables or create my own tables or views.

I have managed to return something very close to what I need. I need to return all the columns of a table with some of the values in a specific column changed.

What I have now:

```
select *, RIGHT(STN1,len(STN1)-1) AS NEW_STNO
FROM WOPSEGS0
WHERE len(STN1) > 0 AND SUBSTRING(STN1,1,1) = '0'
```

This is the change that needs to be made. So, if a STN1 is 08, I need to change it to 8. This code returns that result, but it omits everything that hasn't been changed ex(STN1 = 25). My thought was to somehow embed an update function inside of a select statement to return what normally would just be the new table I created by simply using the update table function.

What I have:

```
STN1       STCD
00         AZ
00         AZ
01         CA
12         NV
```

what I need:

```
STN1       STCD
0          AZ
0          AZ
1          CA
12         NV
```

I can return:

```
STN1       STCD
0          AZ
0          AZ
1          CA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a case expression to determine whether to strip the `0` or not.

```
declare @WOPSEGS0 table (STN1 varchar(2), STCD varchar(2))

insert into @WOPSEGS0 (STN1, STCD)
  select '00', 'AZ' union all
  select '00', 'AZ' union all
  select '01', 'CA' union all
  select '12', 'NV'

select *
  , case when SUBSTRING(STN1,1,1) = '0' then RIGHT(STN1,len(STN1)-1) else STN1 end as NEW_STNO
FROM @WOPSEGS0
WHERE len(STN1) > 0 --AND SUBSTRING(STN1,1,1) = '0'
```

PS: This is the preferred method of posting SQL questions where you provide the DDL & DML statements required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is casting it to `int` and then casting it again to `varchar(2)` (Unless you are OK keeping it as int, in which case the second cast would not be necessary).

```
SELECT STN1,STCD, CAST(CAST(STN1 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS NEW_STNO
FROM WOPSEGS0
```

Comment: Even better, handles all numbers of leading zeros.