# Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 6 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

from this SQL code of mine:

```
CASE 
   WHEN CHARINDEX('-', JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number) = 0 
      THEN JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number 
   WHEN CHARINDEX('-', JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number) >= 4 
      THEN LEFT(JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number, CHARINDEX('-', JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number) -1) 
   WHEN CHARINDEX('Reb:', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) >= 1 
      THEN SUBSTRING(JE.JrnlEntry_Description, CHARINDEX('Reb:', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) + 4, CHARINDEX(',', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) - (CHARINDEX('Reb:', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) + 4))  ---LOOKS FOR THE REFERENCE NUMBER IN THE THE DESCRIPTION
   ELSE JE.JrnlEntry_Description
END AS [REBATE ID]
```

Below are distinct JrnlEntry_Description field results-

```
Reb: 5925.16, Mfgr: INTERWEST BILLING, Site: 00037
Reb: 3270.17 - OFR
Reb: 8281 Nestle Select Items P5 2018
```

Comment: And what about sample data for `JrnlEntry_Reference_Number`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add additional information. You need your sample data to be in tabular form and be such that it reproduces the issue.

Comment: Sample data for JrnlEntry_Reference_Number     672822 , 1576386 , 568993 , 424897-19 , E00000000051911 , 57521321, 59459643

Comment: So if you could please familiarise yourself with code and data formatting. I already formatted your question for you, but you've removed it all. Finally please don't post images of data - it needs to be in text for to allow it to be copy and pasted out by the person who assists you.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57210836/1127428) for the recommended way to post data and an SQL problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, first two usage of `CHARINDEX` ( for  `CHARINDEX('-',JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number)` )  and one usage of `LEFT` functions ( for `LEFT(JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number, ...` ) has `JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number` value as the `second` and `first` arguments respectively.

Both considered arguments' values should be `string` and seems `JE.JrnlEntry_Reference_Number` is a numeric value and the error seems raising due to this mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the comma here is suspicious:

```
  WHEN CHARINDEX('Reb:', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) >= 1  
  THEN SUBSTRING(JE.JrnlEntry_Description,
                 CHARINDEX('Reb:', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) + 4,
                 (CHARINDEX(',', JE.JrnlEntry_Description
  --------------------------^
                           ) -
                  (CHARINDEX('Reb:', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) + 4)
                 )
                )  ---LOOKS FOR THE REFERENCE NUMBER IN THE THE DESCRIPTION
```

You could fix this in two ways.  One is to change the `WHEN`:

```
  WHEN JE.JrnlEntry_Description LIKE '%Reb:%,%'
```

But you probably want the comma to be optional.  This will work *assuming there is no comma before `'Reb:'`:

```
  THEN SUBSTRING(JE.JrnlEntry_Description,
                 CHARINDEX('Reb:', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) + 4,
                 (CHARINDEX(',', JE.JrnlEntry_Description + ','
  --------------------------------------------------------^ should fix the problem
                           ) -
                  (CHARINDEX('Reb:', JE.JrnlEntry_Description) + 4)
                 )
                )  ---LOOKS FOR THE REFERENCE NUMBER IN THE THE DESCRIPTION
```